# Svelte related child component reload on change of neighbour component

Tags: svelte

Attempting to use svelte/sveltekit to have a reactive component in an invoice type tabular layout (i.e. multiple instances of children components).

Illustration below shows the basic layout

[image: Example layout]

Essentially when the user changes the "Product" select menu this triggers an update to the "Option" select menu for the corresponding line item as it will change based on the selected item in the product menu.

In a current vanilla JavaScript implementation the steps are as follows

1. Attach event handler to every instance of the "Product" select menu
2. onChange of this menu, get the selected "id" and pass to a fetch to an api
3. fetch the colors for this "product" id
4. Recreate the "Option" select menu with the matching main "id" and the qty columns for the product/option combo

The Product menu is created from load function as follows

```
<select name="product_id-{item.invoice_item_id}" class="form-select form-select-sm"
              bind:value={item.product_id}
              on:change={?????}
              >
                {#each products as product}
                  <option value={product.product_id}>{product.name}</option>
                {/each}
              </select>
```

The Option/Color menu is created in onMount() using the following format

```
<select name="product_option_color_id-{iteration}" class="form-select form-select-sm"
bind:value={product_option_color_id_selected}>
    {#each colors as color}
      <option value="{color.color_id}">{color.color_name}</option>
    {/each}
  </select>
```

My question is how to I attach/manage the on:change event above on product_id-{item.invoice_item_id}. Would I simply do as I would in vanilla js and grab the id of this element, call the fetch function and then re-create the Option select menu with the new data or is there a cleaner svelte way where I can bind to the change event from the first select menu.

Comment: All seems well explained, but where's the question?

Comment: Wishing to get advice on best way to handle this cleanly using svelte. How do I add a dynamic on:change={} to the product select menu to then trigger a re-load/re-fetch of the option menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the {#key } block around the child component. The option select menu represented in the question was moved to a component named Colors.svelte. Then in the parent component it was rendered as follows

```
{#key item.product_id}
  <Colors {product_id} />
{/key}
```

Thus when product_id was changed in the product select menu a reloading of the Colors child component was initiated with the new product_id prop. Svelte magic at its best!

With thanks to this blog post that helped educate me on the solution.

https://www.okupter.com/blog/rerender-svelte-components

Answer (score 0):

Cascading in a form is very easy with Svelte.  All you need to do is calculate the options of the child Select whenever the value of its parent Select changes.  There is no need for any `on:change` event.  That would be imperative programming, and Svelte (like React and many others) is all about declarative programming.

Have a look at this [live REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/308358a5d8f6450086d508e09005208e?version=4.2.1).

### Explanation

First, the code:

```html
<script>
    const products = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Polo Shirt'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Long-Sleeve Shirt'
        }
    ];

    const colors = {
        "0": [],
        "1": [
            {
                id: 101,
                name: 'Navy Blue',
                sample: 'navy'
            },
            {
                id: 102,
                name: 'pink',
                sample: 'pink'
            }
        ],
        "2": [
            {
                id: 201,
                name: 'Light Blue',
                sample: 'lightblue'
            },
            {
                id: 202,
                name: 'Magenta',
                sample: 'magenta'
            }
        ]
    };

    let currentProduct = null;
    let currentColor = null;
</script>

<h1>Cascading Dropdowns</h1>

<main>
    <article>
        <h2>Ficticious Form</h2>
        <div>
            <label>
                Select Product:
                <select bind:value={currentProduct}>
                    <option value={null}>Select One</option>
                    {#each products as product (product.id)}
                        <option value={product}>{product.name}</option>
                    {/each}
                </select>
            </label>
            <label>
                Select Color:
                <select bind:value={currentColor}>
                    <option value={null}>Select One</option>
                    {#each colors[currentProduct?.id ?? 0] as color (color.id)}
                        <option value={color}>{color.name}</option>
                    {/each}
                </select>
            </label>
            <span
                class="color-sample"
                style:background-color={currentColor?.sample ?? 'transparent'}
            >
                &nbsp;
            </span>
        </div>
    </article>
</main>

<style>
    span.color-sample {
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 2em;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

The answer to your question would be in the second `{#each}` block.  The collection of colors change immediately after selecting a product.  The example doesn't use an API and merely declares a dictionary of colors, where the dictionary key is the product ID.  So `colors[currentProduct?.id ?? 0]` is simply requesting the array of colors that belong to the selected product.

This statement is reactive by the book of Svelte, so simply by changing the product selection, the color list is recalculated.

Comment: Thank you for that, I was going down this road but stumbled on how I extend this logic to multiple form line items as shown in my example screenshot. How do you set currentProduct , currentColor to unique bindings. e.g. something like:

<select bind:value={currentProduct[i]}>

as in my scenario the Select product menu will be wrapped in an outer each statement